# Value em Select2 multi select

Tags: jquery-select2, jquery-ui-multiselect

Boa tarde,

Estou com dificuldades de retornar os valores de N itens selecionados com o select2, ele retornar apenas o primeiro. Estou usando asp.net.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMeses" runat="server" 
                  class="js-example-basic-multiple menorselect2"
                  onchange="todos()" 
                  multiple="true"> 
    <asp:ListItem Value="13">Todos os meses</asp:ListItem> 
    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Jan</asp:ListItem> 
    <asp:ListItem Value="12">Dez</asp:ListItem> 
</asp:DropDownList>

Dim listOfValues AS List(Of String) = new List(Of String)
        For Each item As ListItem In ddLokasi.Items
            If item.Selected Then
                listOfValues.Add(item.Value)
            End If
        Next
```

Comment: posta o que voce tem de codigo para que possamos te ajudar Fabio

Comment: Voce pode editar a questao usando o link Editar que esta embaixo do seu post Fabio